# Jquery Animate six image horizontally in line path

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation, jquery-animate

i have created image animation with 3 image in which , initially only 1 image displayed then after animation of 1st image complete then same with second at a time only two image i have to display and if 3rd image come then i have to hide first image , i want this type of animation for all 6 images but i am stuck after 4th image , help me to resolve this or suggest me any other js that can make my work done.many thanks.

here is my fiddle : [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sona824/xhbt1yfx/)

Following is code :

**HTML**

```
 <div style="float:left;position: relative;left: 300px" id="b">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/top_chart_track_number_one-128.png" class="image1">
</div>
<div style="float:left;position: relative;display: none;" id="b1">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/track_number_two_circle-128.png" class="image2">
</div>
<div style="float:left;position: relative;display: none;" id="b2">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/three_top_chart_track-128.png" class="image3">
</div>
<div style="float:left;position: relative;display: none;" id="b3">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/top_number_four_track_chart_circle-128.png" class="image3">
</div>
<div style="float:left;position: relative;display: none;" id="b4">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/top_five_chart_track_list-128.png" class="image3">
</div>
<div style="float:left;position: relative;display: none;" id="b5">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/number_six_circle_chart_list_track-128.png" class="image3">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b").animate({left: "-=300"},2000);
        $("#b").animate({left: "+=80"}, 1000);
var counter = 1;
setInterval(function()
{
    ++counter;
    console.log(counter);
    if(counter=='2')
    {

    }
    else if(counter=='7')
    {
      $("#b").animate({left: "-=80"},1000); 
    }
    else if(counter=='4')
    {
        $("#b1").fadeIn('slow');
        $("#b1").animate({left: "+=300"},2000);
        $("#b1").animate({left: "-=280"}, 1000);
    }
    else if(counter=='8')
    {
        console.log('enter');
        $("#b2").fadeIn('slow');
        $("#b2").animate({left: "+=300"},2000);
        $("#b2").animate({left: "-=500"}, 1000);
    }
    else if(counter=='11')
    {
        console.log('enter');
        $("#b").animate({left: "-=300"}, 1000);
        $("#b1").animate({left: "-=260"}, 1000);
        $("#b2").animate({left: "-=0"}, 1000);
        //$("#b").hide('1000');
    }
}, 1000); });
```

Comment: Paste the related code here.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev here is code , see edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a pain to add all that animation code for each element, especially if you decide to add more in the future. How about having a recursive function like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $first = $('.number').first();
    slider($first, true);
    
    function slider($first, firstPass) {
        var $second = $first.next();
        var $third = $second.next();

        if (firstPass) {
            $first.fadeIn('slow');
            $first.animate({ left: "0" }, 2000, function () {
                $first.animate({ left: "80px" }, 1000, function () {
                    loop();
                });
            });
        } else {
            loop();
        }

        function loop() {
            $second.css('left', '120px').fadeIn('slow');
            $second.animate({ left: "400px" }, 2000, function () {
                $first.delay(500).animate({ left: "0" }, 1000);
                $second.animate({ left: "150px" }, 1000, function () {
                    // If there is no third element, we can stop here.
                    if ($third.length > 0) {
                        $third.css('left', '250px').fadeIn('slow');
                        $first.delay(2500).animate({ left: "-600px" }, 1000, function () {
                            $first.fadeOut();
                        });
                        $second.delay(3000).animate({ left: "-300px" }, 1000, function () {
                            $second.fadeOut();
                        });
                        $third.animate({ left: "550px" }, 2000, function () {
                            $third.animate({ left: "80px" }, 1000, function () {
                                // Start again and set the third element as the new first.
                                slider($third, false);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.number {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

#b {
    left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number" id="b">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/top_chart_track_number_one-128.png" class="image1">
</div>
<div class="number" id="b1">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/track_number_two_circle-128.png" class="image2">
</div>
<div class="number" id="b2">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/three_top_chart_track-128.png" class="image3">
</div>
<div class="number" id="b3">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/top_number_four_track_chart_circle-128.png" class="image3">
</div>
<div class="number" id="b4">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/top_five_chart_track_list-128.png" class="image3">
</div>
<div class="number" id="b5">
    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/online-menu/64/number_six_circle_chart_list_track-128.png" class="image3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that the code only handles first three circles (seconds 1-11).
Further animation is provided by adding cases for later seconds.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w725v9yn/) that adds one case to show you that circle "4" is indeed displayed. But I believe it is upto you to make the final solution of it.

relevant code section is:

```
else if (counter == '14') {
    console.log('enter 14');
    $("#b3").fadeIn('slow');
    $("#b").animate({
        left: "0"
    }, 1000);
    $("#b1").animate({
        left: "30"
    }, 1000);
    $("#b2").animate({
        left: "60"
    }, 1000);
    $("#b3").animate({
        left: "200"
    }, 1000);
    //$("#b").hide('1000');
}
```

Comment: the problem is as i add more left style property for image 4 , 5 6 i cant figure out what to do with other circle , it mashes up everything.

Comment: As I see it, the if-else in your code is more like a time-line. Every x'th second, there is an animation rendered. Now how you go about that is by referring to the code for first three circles' animation. I suppose providing a full solution is not what you'd expect from us here.

Comment: @Sona One other thing worth mentioning is a problem with over-scrolling. The width of images and the space required by for animation is somewhere around 350px. So you're looking at 2100px width.. is this right?

Comment: no , i want all 6 images in 350px only , i want to show all images one by one like following sequence like      (a) 1(b) 1,2 (c) 2,3 (d) 3,4 (e)4,5 (f)5,6 and finaly only 1,2,3